# how to query a complex property in google cloud datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I have an entity created in Datastore with a complex property (or document? I don't know exactly what to call it! Please tell me the correct name for it) which looks like this:

```
taskId: "T101",
taskType: "Pick",    
itemInfo:
{
 "id":"00014",
 "actualQty":"1",
 "attributes":[{"value":"Large","name":"Size"},"value":"Blue","name":"Color"}],
 "requiredQty":"10",
 "imageUrl":" ",
 "upc":"886654801"
}
```

I want to query on the upc field in the itemInfo property. (Please don't ask me to move upc out of itemInfo property!). I know that for querying anything we need to have index defined and I have taskId in my index.yaml.

something like:

```
select * from Task where itemInfo.upc = "<some value>";
```

Please tell me we can do it somehow!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the entity Kind is `Task` in the Datastore, and that it has `taskId`, `taskType` and `itemInfo` properties, with `itemInfo` being embedded entity, the query you mentioned should work fine.

```
SELECT * FROM Task WHERE itemInfo.upc='886654801'
```

Just keep in mind that property names and values are case sensitive. Also, `itemInfo` property should be indexed.